# Required bean is not found in Controller - Error during dependency injection

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a very simple spring boot application with a simple hardcoded service but it is not working and it is giving me `Field userService in hello.UserController required a bean of type 'services.UserService' that could not be found` error. Here are my Application class, controller and service class. The problem is when I try to inject the userService via `@Autowired` annotation. I think this is already answered somewhere but I cannot find the relevant answer. Please help me or point me to the right answer. Thanks

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RequestMapping("/api")

public class UserController {

public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> listAllUsers() {
    List<User> users = userService.getAllUsers();
    if(users.isEmpty()) return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);

    return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

**Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = 
{UserController.class})
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Bean
public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
    return args -> {

        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }

    };
 }

}
```

**Service class**

```
@Service

public class UserService {

List<User> users;

public UserService() {
    this.users = new ArrayList<>();
    users.add(new User(2, "Altaire", 23));
    users.add(new User(3, "Ezio", 21));
    users.add(new User(4, "Enzo", 23));
}

public User getUser(int id) {
    for (User user : users) {
        if (user.getId() == id) {
            return user;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void addUser(User user) {
    users.add(user);
}

public void deleteUser(int id) {
    for (User user : users) {
        if (user.getId() == id) {
            users.remove(user);
        }
    }
}

public void updateUser(int id, String name, int age) {
    for (User user : users) {
        if (user.getId() == id) {
            user.setName(name);
            user.setAge(age);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you should show also the packages and imports as it matters.

Comment: The service class is in module named services and Controller and Application class is in a different module

Comment: There is no such thing as a module in Java (at least, not before Java 9). Why don't you just do what you're being asked to do: post the code with its package and import statements?

Answer (score 0):

In the application class you have

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = 
{UserController.class})
```

You should add the service class as well:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = 
{UserController.class,UserService.class})
```

Note that you can also use scanBasePackages and not only explicit classed, e.g.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackage = {"com.x.y"})
```

Comment: If you start to declare each bean in `scanBasePackageClasses` , your configuration is really unmaintainable and you loose the scan benefit.

Comment: That's why I suggested to use scanBasePackages

Comment: I saw it. But  you should not even suggest the first way, overall as the main solution. It is an anti pattern of Spring.